# Error when importing local component file into my LoginForm component

Tags: javascript, react-native, import

I am new to react-native but I have successfully imported local files into another before and I am getting this error message:

```
Unable to resolve "./common" from "src/components/LoginForm.js"
```

I am using expo XDE for the first time as well if that provides any insight. This seems so simple but I can't seem to find if I have a typo.

Here is a screenshot of my project file structure:

[image]

These are my imports in LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Form, FormSection } from './common';         // what am i doing wrong with this????
```

These are my imports in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './src/components/LoginForm';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create an `index.js` in your `/common`, Then export all of you components:

```
export * from "./Button";
export * from "./Card";
export * from "./CardSection";
export * from "./Header";
export * from "./Input";
export * from "./Spinner";
```

also be sure to `export { YourComponentName };` in each file as well!

Comment: Wow.. needless to say I won't be forgetting that step again.Thank you!

Comment: Good luck! I would appreciate if you vote up my answer for further references.

Comment: When my reputation is higher I will